# Bug with minitoc and one­half­s­pac­ing text

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, minitoc, setspace

I'm using [minitoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) and [setspace](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) packages (the former to set text spacing to onehalfspacing).

As you can see in the screenshots and MWE below, a graphical bug occurs when using both packages (with `onehalfspacing` option for setspace}. When `onehalfspacing` option is active, the first item of the table of contents is set too close to the line created by `minitoc`.

The `minitoc` maintainer (Jean-Pierre Drucbert) is deceased and no one (in my knowledge) took over. I am pessimistic about a fix thus.

Do you think of a workaround to have both `onehalfspacing` text and `minitoc` for part working together?

The problem:
[image]

Without the `\onehalfspacing` option, no problem:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{minitoc}

\doparttoc

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\faketableofcontents

\onehalfspacing


\part{1st part}
\parttoc


\chapter{With OneHalfSpacing, the Title is Too Close to the Line}

\singlespacing
\parttoc


\chapter{With SingleSpacing, No Problem}

\end{document}
```

EDIT : The same problem appears if I remove `palatino` package. We just see "less" the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you remove the `palatino` package, both ToCs look alike

Comment: @ChristianHupfer We see less the problem with standard fonts but the line is still closer in the first case than in the second (see my edit). But maybe I can use this workaround if nobody offers another solution. Thanks!

Comment: `minitoc` is a very sophisticated package, with more than 5000 lines of code. The manual is overwhelming (and sometimes confusing), providing a different solution requires some excavation activities. As you said, the package is not maintained, the latest release from 2015 was more than six years after J. Drucbert passed away (:-(((). I have some knowledge about ToCs etc., but I am not going to step forward and shout: I will maintain the package ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround which should do for `\parttoc`.

The macro `\parttoc@` performs

```
\leavevmode\\\mtc@BBR\vskip -.5\baselineskip
```

right at its end, i.e. shifting the position upwards for the next content. 
While this is alright for a normal skip value it is too much most likely for the `\baselineskip` values provided by `\onehalfspacing` etc.

The easiest thing is to define a correcting length, say, `\mtc@startparttocbaselineskip` and set it to `0pt` and applying a patch! This way, there is no spacing - depending upshift.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\mtc@startparttocbaselineskip}
\setlength{\mtc@startparttocbaselineskip}{0pt}

\xpatchcmd{\parttoc@}{%
  \leavevmode\\\mtc@BBR\vskip -.5\baselineskip
}{%
  \leavevmode\\\mtc@BBR\vskip -\mtc@startparttocbaselineskip
}{\typeout{Patch successfully performed}}{\typeout{Patch failed!}}
\makeatother




\doparttoc

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\faketableofcontents
\part{1st part}
\parttoc

\chapter{With OneHalfSpacing, the Title is Too Close to the Line}
\chapter{With SingleSpacing, No Problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I intentionally did not remove the `\vskip` completely there. Perhaps another spacing might be desired as well.